# SQL Server 2012 : compare t1.field1 value to t2.field1 value before updating

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have table1 which has my initial records. I have `table2` which contains the same table structure as `table1`. `Table2` transactions are used to update `table1` values.

To illustrate what I am trying to do, I have this code which works nicely for fields when they are null:

```
UPDATE TABLE1
SET FIELD1 = CASE WHEN T1.FIELD1 = '' THEN t2.FIELD1 ELSE T1.FIELD1 END,
    FIELD2 = CASE WHEN T1.FIELD2 = '' THEN T2.FIELD2 ELSE T1.FIELD2 END,
    FIELD3 = CASE WHEN T1.FIELD3 = '' THEN T2.FIELD3 ELSE T1.FIELD3 END,
FROM TABLE1 T1 
JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.COMMONFIELD = T2.COMMONFIELD
GO
```

But is there a way to do the same, but compare `t1.field1` value to `t2.field1` value with the same kind of logic?  This would be the concept with similar code:

```
UPDATE TABLE1
SET FIELD1 = CASE WHEN T1.FIELD1 > t2.field1 THEN t2.FIELD1 ELSE T1.FIELD1 END,
    FIELD2 = CASE WHEN T1.FIELD2 < t2.field2 THEN T2.FIELD2 ELSE T1.FIELD2 END,
    FIELD3 = CASE WHEN T1.FIELD3 = '' THEN T2.FIELD3 ELSE T1.FIELD3 END,
FROM TABLE1 T1 
JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.COMMONFIELD = T2.COMMONFIELD
GO
```

I want to be able to compare `t1.field-n` values to `t2.field-n` values where each has it's own compare criteria before the update.  If not this approach, is this possible to do using T-SQL another way?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  Your first query does not explicitly handle `NULL`s, so I have no idea why you think it handles them well.  The logic isn't clear.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  You are correct.  It handles spaces.  And thank you for formatting, where is the info on how to do that?

Comment: You may want to create functions `least()` and `greatest()` to carry out the comparison logic in your second query.  These functions are present in several DBMSs, although not SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly an answer, but I would expect your first query to be:

```
UPDATE T1
    SET FIELD1 = COALESCE(T2.FIELD1, T1.FIELD1),
        FIELD2 = COALESCE(T2.FIELD2, T1.FIELD2),
        FIELD3 = COALESCE(T2.FIELD3, T1.FIELD3)
FROM TABLE1 T1 JOIN
     TABLE2 T2
     ON T1.COMMONFIELD = T2.COMMONFIELD;
```

This will update `TABLE1`, when the corresponding field in `TABLE2` is `NOT NULL`.  I'm not sure what the rest of your question is about, but you might as well have the first query do something sensible.

Comment: The overall process is to combine a group of common rows and create a master record.  The fields that are blank or have spaces are filled in with their corresponding similar field from another table that have values.  I was focusing more on the case statement within the update which allows you to look at whether t1.field1 has spaces, and if it does, update it with t2.field1.  But what if you want to compare the 2 values to each other instead.  And the update rule for field1 is different than the update rule for field2.  There are 60 fields, 1.5 million records.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if following will help you or not:

```
declare @t1 table (val1 varchar(100), val2 varchar(100), common_field int)
declare @t2 table (val1 varchar(100), val2 varchar(100), common_field int)

insert into @t1 
select 'abc', 'first', 1 union select '', 'second', 2 union select 'xyz', '', 3 union select '', '', 4

insert into @t2
select '', 'NEW_FIRST', 1 union select 'NEW', 'NEW_2', 2 union select 'not_old', 'NEW_SECOND', 3 union select 'PQR_NEW', 'ALL_NEW', 4

select t1.common_field, t1.val1 val1_1, t2.val1 val1_2,
coalesce(nullif(t1.val1, ''), t2.val1) update_value_for_val1,
t1.val2 val2_1, t2.val2 val2_2,
coalesce(nullif(t1.val2, ''), t2.val2) update_value_for_val2
from @t1 t1
join @t2 t2 on t1.common_field = t2.common_field
order by 1
```

Thanks.